# Snort Rule to Detect Base64 Encoding

Tags: regex, pcre, snort

I am trying to incorporate the following Regex to a snort rule to detect base64 in outbound ICMP traffic: `^-A-Za-z0-9+/=]|=[^=]|={3,}$`

I did not write this expression myself, however I tested it and it seems to work in http://regexe.com/ just fine.

The snort rule: `alert icmp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:“Base64 detected in outbound ICMP traffic (possible ICMP tunnelling!)";pcre"^-A-Za-z0-9+/=]|=[^=]|={3,}$";)`

I understand snort uses Perl Compatible Regex which might explain the discrepancy, however I am not skilled enough to find out what needs to be changed to fix this. I get the following error when I add this rule to the `/etc/snort/rules/local.rules file`: `ERROR: /etc/snort/rules/local.rules Line 8 => unable to parse pcre regex "^-A-Za-z0-9+/=]|=[^=]|={3,}$"`

Anyone able to assist?

Regards,

Comment: Aren't you missing a `[` after the initial `^`?

Comment: I added that and get the following output:                                                                              unable to parse pcre regex "^[-A-Za-z0-9+/=]|=[^=]|={3,}$"

Answer (score 0):

i believe your missing the beginning and ending \ to declare pcre in a snort signature so it should look like

```
pcre:"\^[-A-Za-z0-9+/=]|=[^=]|={3,}$\";
```